# zsh: excluding files from a pattern

Tags: shell-script, zsh, wildcards

Say I have the following files:

> ```
> |-- bar
> `-- foo
>     |-- type_A_1
>     |-- type_A_2
>     |-- type_B_1
>     |-- type_B_2
>     |-- type_B_xx
>     |-- type_B_xx
>     `-- something_else
> ```

I thought the following command

```
print -l foo/*~{type_B*}
```

would print **everything** under `foo` **except** things that start with `type_B` but it doesn't, instead it prints everything under foo:

```
foo/type_A_1
foo/type_A_2
foo/type_B_1
foo/type_B_2
foo/type_B_xx
foo/something_else
```

I also tried `print -l foo/*~type_B` and got the same thing.

How does the exception wildcard `~` work in zsh?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include the directory into the exception: `print -l foo/*~foo/type_A*` or `print -l foo/*~{foo/type_A*}`.

If you want, you can replace the directory by a wildcard:
 `print -l foo/*~*/type_A*`

Comment: Thanks! About the second pattern, do you mind explaining how the pattern `foo/*~*/type_A*` works? Does the second `*` expand to **every** folder under the working directory, or is it smart enough to only expand to `foo`?

Comment: @roseck Because it seems really fast (for example when you run `print *~**/*` in the `/` directory), I assume that it first expand the first pattern and then remove all matches which fit to the exclusion pattern.

Comment: @roseck `~` is purely textual, the part before the `~` expands as it always would, then the part after strips away matches. ​＠jofel A better test would be `print /**/*~*`: you can observe that it traverses the whole tree, even if it ends up printing nothing.

Comment: I thought he wanted to exclude type_B but include type_A.

Comment: Right answer is below

Comment: The part after the ~ is not purely textual, but the ~ is the lowest precedence operator within the command (any single command, actually). That means the left half is evaluated, then the right half, then filtering is done. The ^ operator can be used for individual path components, but it is unary "not" rather than set subtraction.

Answer (score 44):

*zsh* has the `^` glob operator when EXTENDED_GLOB is on. It seems like the perfect fit for your stated situation:

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl foo/^type_A*
```

It means “match anything, except what matches the following pattern”, but its effect is limited to the portion of the pattern between slashes, or between the beginning of the pattern and the first slash, or (as in this case) between the last slash and the end of the pattern.

You can view the *zsh* options currently enabled with:

```
setopt
```

And disable EXTENDED_GLOB with:

```
unsetopt extendedglob
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pipe your output into `grep -v` to in*v*ert the grep:

```bash
# list all filenames in foo not including "type_B"
ls foo/ | grep -v type_B
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that the question is "How does the exception wildcard ~ work in zsh?"